# Multiplication of complex numbers $(3-2i)(\cos2t+i\sin2t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the problem below.

$$\mathrm{Re}((3-2i)(\cos2t+i\sin2t))$$

Multiplication of complex numbers gives me the following:

$$\mathrm{Re}((3\cos2t+2\sin2t)+i(3\sin2t-2\cos2t))$$

But what do I do thereafter?

(The solution will be $2\sin2t+3\cos2t$).

Comment: Are you sure it is Im and not Re?

Comment: What you say is the solution is the real part of that product. Check carefully the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the real part-that is the answer you provide.

In general form, let $z_1,z_2 \in ℂ ,z_1=x_1+iy_1, z_2=x_2+iy_2$
$$z_1z_2=x_1x_2-y_1y_2+i(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)$$
So you can find the real and imaginary parts by this last equivalence.

Comment: Correct, it is the real part, and that is a really simple way of doing it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the multiplication with care:
\begin{align}
(3-2i)(\cos2t+i\sin2t)
&=3\cos2t-2i\cos2t+3i\sin2t-2i^2\sin2t\\
&=(3\cos2t+2\sin2t)+i(3\sin2t-2\cos2t)
\end{align}
so the imaginary part is
$$
3\sin2t-2\cos2t
$$
whereas the real part is
$$
3\cos2t+2\sin2t
$$
That's all.